# Need help organizing difference in types for BSP geometry rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, bsp

I am currently trying to convert another format to the Quake 3 BSP format. The Quake format includes verticies, faces, indicies, and textures.

From the information I have to work with:

I have verticies which are the 3 floating point structures for the x, y and z location.

I have the polygons which I could assume are the faces. The polygons are all triangular and are references to the vertex indexes and textures.

I have the textures formatted correctly.

My main questions are:

1. Are faces in the BSP format equivalent to polygons?
2. What are indicies in a BSP format? Are they indicies to verticies or to more than that?

Answer (score 0):

Quake3's BSP format represents all faces as triangles (sometimes called "triangle soup" by programmers). This is more efficient for the hardware to render than Quake2's format, where faces could be arbitrarily sided polygons (3+ vertices). When all faces are triangles, you can draw multiple faces with a single call, provided that those faces share the same material:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, first_face->index, num_faces);
```

This batching of geometry yields a *massive* performance improvement over Quake2, where because every face might have a different number of vertices, faces cannot be lumped into single draw operations: you must instead call glDrawArrays (or worse, glVertex3f in loop) for every polygon. This key difference is why Quake3's environments can contain 10 times the complexity as Quake2.

Anyway, keep in mind that the indices are not just indices into the vertex lump. They are also indices into the texture coordinates for both the diffuse and lightmap channels. Hope this helps.